# CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed

Tags: android, haxm

I have gone through all the questions related to this and the solutions did not work!
This is error:

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware
>   acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and
>   usable. CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Steps I have taken:

1. From the SDK Manager, I have installed the HAXM Installer.
2. I have 'Enabled' the Virtualization (VT-x) from BIOS.
3. There is no Hiper-V installed in my machine. Hence there is nothing
   to 'uncheck'.

Now, when I try to install the "intelhaxm-android.exe" it is still throwing the error given above.

Can anyone suggest other options to look at?

Thanks.

Comment: Silly question, but did you make sure to actually run the file that the installation downloads? https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x